# How to hide excluded files in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project with hundreds of pages classes and controls. many of them are excluded but as they appear in the project browser they clutter it and make it difficult to find the files I need. I don't want to delete them since every once in a while i get back to them for review. is there any way to show/hide the excluded files with a button toggle?

I don't have the button for show all files. see picture:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is a button to hide/show excluded files.
The button is under solution explorer tab.

Please check this link for VS2008:

http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/09/14/visual-studio-tip-show-all-file/

[image]

**Important Update:**

After trials on VS2012 I found out that if you create New Web Site the hide/show button will not appear for no apparent reason. However, if you create New Project the hide/show button will appear!! So, it seems that you have to avoid creating New Web Site... but create New Project instead to have the button on Solution explorer. Try moving your work to a New Project rather than your current solution Good Luck!

Comment: You have to highlight the hidden file or hidden folder(excluded file) first in order for the button to show up for you. Check the second image again you will see that I have chosen the excluded file (bin) in my case.

Comment: I don't the button. with single files, multiple files, and for folders, this button doesn't appear... :(

Comment: I see what you mean. After I have tried on VS2012 I found out that if you create New Web Site the hide/show button will not appear. However, if you create New Project the hide/show button will appear!! So, it seems that you have to avoid creating New Web Site... but create New Project instead to have the button on Solution explorer. Try moving your work to a New Project rather than  your current solution Good Luck! That is really weird move from MS unexpected.

Comment: edit your answer to include your last comment for the benefit of the world :)